# how to float the element outside the container?

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I'm trying to float the image with the text "top Score" outside the parent div `#wrapper`

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class = "col1-content">
             <div class="ribbon left">
                <h2>My top Score</h2>
             </div>

        </div> <!-- col1-content -->
</div>

#wrapper .col1-content .ribbon{
    position: absolute;
    width:330px;
    height: 89px;
    z-index: 10;

}

#wrapper .col1-content .left{
    background:url(../images/ribbon_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    left: -35px;
}

#wrapper .para h2{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I retrieved the image and uploaded it elsewhere for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class = "col1-content">
             <div class="ribbon left">
                <h2>My top Score</h2>
             </div>
            <div class="para-score">
                <ul>
                    <li id="avatar"></li>
                    <li id="name"></li>
                    <li id="score"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- col1-content -->
</div>

#wrapper {position:relative;}

#wrapper .left{
    background:url(../images/ribbon_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    left: -35px;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Still the problem exists. Any insight??

Answer (score 0):

Your text is disappearing on that page because the class you are using "left: -35px;" has a relative position. You should either assign it an absolute position or move the "left: -35px;" to the .ribbon class.

```
#wrapper .col1-content .ribbon{
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    width:330px;
    height: 89px;
    z-index: 10;

}

#wrapper .col1-content .left{
    background:url(../images/ribbon_left.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}

#wrapper .para h2{
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:lighter;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```